# Google Tag Manager Click Variables sometimes not populating on click

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm using Google Tag Manager click variables click element and click url to track button clicks on my website.

For some reason, the Click variables are sometimes not populating upon click sending "undefined" data to Google Tag Manager.

For example the BOOK NOW button on this page in both desktop and mobile (http://www.maverickhelicopter.com/mobile/foodie.aspx) often fail to populate click variable data. This is just an example page.

It happens on other pages as well (both desktop and mobile version). If it refresh the page a few times or start a new session and try the click again the variables populate.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Is it an issue with the way Tag Manager is loading, or with the html on the site? Website is built in ASP.net and Google Tag Manager is installed per the instructions provided by Google.

Comment: Can you please add information about your `Click variables` which are not populating sometimes. And also information, how you created trigger

Answer (score 0):

It's happening becuase the actual click element is different depending where exactly you click on your button. From your page:

[image]

Notice how "BOOK NOW" button is not fully highlighted. That means when you click outside of highligted area the browser understands to navigate to href page but actual clicked element in GTM is not the link `<a href="...">` but rather your wrapper `<div style="float:right; width:50%;>` element which does not have url so that's why you can see "undefined"

You can fix it by removing any padding you have set on  link inside your wrapper div.